# Inner Join VS CrossApply

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join, cross-apply

I'm trying to get the same result using two different methods but it appears that 
I'm doing wrong somewhere and I can't figure it out

first Query with innerjoin:

```
with cte as(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY businessentityid desc) AS Row#
from HumanResources.Employee
)
Select A.firstname, B.jobtitle
from Person.Person A
inner join cte B on A.BusinessEntityID = B.BusinessEntityID and B.Row# <= 3
```

Second Query with Cross Apply:

```
Select A.firstname, cte.jobtitle 
from Person.Person A
cross apply 
(
Select top 3 * 
from HumanResources.Employee B
where B.BusinessEntityID= A.BusinessEntityID
order by businessentityid DESC
) cte
```

Am getting two different results, any ideas ??

**Update :**

Thanks to @PriyankJ who gave me the idea,I managed to find the correct query thus the desired result :

```
SELECT  **top 3** cte.FirstName ,B.JobTitle
FROM    **HumanResources.Employee B**
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 3 *
        FROM     **person.person A**
        WHERE   A.BusinessEntityID = B.BusinessEntityID
        ORDER BY
                A.BusinessEntityID DESC
        ) cte
```

the changes(difference between the first and second query) are highlighted :)

Comment: One is using `select distinct` and the other isn't.  I wouldn't expect these to produce the same results.

Comment: appart from distinct cuz I've tried that,I'll edit that to be more indicative

Answer (score 2):

I think the cross apply left table needs to be `HumanResources.Employee` to get the same result.

```
SELECT TOP 3
    cte.firstname
   ,A.jobtitle
FROM HumanResources.Employee A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT
        *
    FROM Person.Person B
    WHERE B.BusinessEntityID = A.BusinessEntityID) cte
ORDER BY cte.BusinessEntityID DESC
```

Comment: Sorry, I've just tried that but it shows whole different results although it's only 3 rows but they are different from the inner join query's result

Comment: I just retried and both(CTE and Cross Apply) are returning same results on my AdventureWorks2014 db.

Comment: this is the result for  the inner join :

#firstname            | jobtitle #
-------------------------------------------------
Ken Chief  | Executive Officer
Terri           | Vice President of Engineering
Roberto   | Engineering Manager

And here is the result I get for the crossapply :

#firstname          |jobtitle#
----------------------------------------
Ranjit   |Sales Representative
Jae Sales  |Representative
Rachel   |Sales Representative

Comment: Result from both queries......firstname,jobtitle,BusinessEntityID----------------
Ranjit,Sales Representative,290
Jae,Sales Representative,289
Rachel,Sales Representative,288

Comment: I got different result and i'm also using adventureworks which is totally bizarre

Comment: Yes that weird. Share me the link from where you got your adventureworks db copy so I can use the same. This is the one I'm using https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/download/adventureworks/AdventureWorks2014.bak

Comment: The same link except that I use the AdventureWorks2017

Comment: Your query need jus some modifications:

Add a top 3 inside the CTE,
the order by clause need to be inside the cte 

that way I'm gonna get the same result, I'll update the question and share the right answer, thank you because you gave me the idea :)

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

So you asked 'why.'  This may help.

It's important to understand better what JOIN and CROSS APPLY are really doing.

Consider this schema:

```
DECLARE @Person as Table (BusinessEntityID int, firstname varchar(10))
DECLARE @Employee as Table (BusinessEntityID int, jobtitle varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @Person (BusinessEntityID, firstname) Values
(1,'Annie'), (2,'Brad'), (3,'Coraline'),  (4,'David')

INSERT INTO @Employee (BusinessEntityID, jobtitle) Values
(1,'Director'), (2,'Manager'), (3,'Analyst'), (4,'Gopher')
```

And your first query

```
with cte as(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY businessentityid desc) AS Row#
from @Employee
)
Select A.firstname, B.jobtitle
from @Person A
inner join cte B on A.BusinessEntityID = B.BusinessEntityID and B.Row# <= 3
```

Which returns this:

```
firstname  jobtitle
---------- ----------
Brad       Manager
Coraline   Analyst
David      Gopher
```

Your CTE is being limited to the top 3 records by BusinessEntityID (descending).  So Annie isn't in that set.  Then we do inner join, which returns all records from both sets that match on the joined column.  So, Director from the Employee table falls out, and our final set is 3 records.  But what's the cross apply doing?

```
Select A.firstname, cte.jobtitle
from @Person A
cross apply 
(
Select top 3 * 
from @Employee B
where B.BusinessEntityID= A.BusinessEntityID
order by businessentityid DESC
) cte

firstname  jobtitle
---------- ----------
Annie      Direcor
Brad       Manager
Coraline   Analyst
David      Gopher
```

This is different.  CROSS APPLY doesn't match the two sets on a joined column.  *Rather, it evaluates the right side for every row on the left side*.  There's four rows in Person, and for each one, Cross Apply selects the top 3 records from Employee that will match that row on BusinessEntityID (because of the where clause).  That's going to give you 4 rows.  Let's change our Employee table a little.

```
INSERT INTO @Employee (BusinessEntityID, jobtitle) Values 
(1,'Direcor'),(2,'Manager'),(3,'Analyst'),(4,'Gopher'),(4,'Blacksmith')
```

We've added a Blacksmith with a duplicate Entity id. What do we get?

JOIN LOGIC

```
firstname  jobtitle
---------- ----------
Coraline   Analyst
David      Gopher
David      Blacksmith
```

CROSS APPLY LOGIC

```
firstname  jobtitle
---------- ----------
Annie      Direcor
Brad       Manager
Coraline   Analyst
David      Gopher
David      Blacksmith
```

We see that in the joined CTE, the duplicated id has pushed one of our smaller id's off the list of top 3 BusinessEntityIds, and David shows up twice where we've joined on the duplicated IDs.

In the cross apply, we have our four rows from Person, and the top three rows from Employee that match each one of those rows from person.  In the case of BusinessEntityID = 4, there are two matches and we get both of them.

The most important point is that Cross apply is evaluating the right side in the context of each row on the left.  Join just goes and returns the rows that match.

If you want your Cross Join query to imitate the same 'filtering' effect that an inner join can create, then you must put the table that will be limited on the left side of the cross join.

```
;with cte as(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY businessentityid desc) AS Row#
from @Employee
)
Select A.firstname, B.jobtitle
from cte B
cross join @Person A 
where A.BusinessEntityID = B.BusinessEntityID and B.Row# <= 3



firstname  jobtitle
---------- ----------
David      Gopher
David      Blacksmith
Coraline   Analyst
```

Comment: I know understand more the concept behind each one of them, but isn't there any solution to use cross apply to return us the same result ?

Comment: I'm using AdventureWorks2017 Database, and still don't get the same result, and I guess that you're getting the same result because the 2 tables contains few records , also you can see that the returned result is not really the same in term of order which means that if you got more records you'll have something different

Answer (score 0):

what you need is 'outer apply'. Try this:

```
Select A.firstname, cte.jobtitle 
from Person.Person A
outer apply 
(
Select top 3 * 
    from HumanResources.Employee B
    where B.BusinessEntityID= A.BusinessEntityID
    order by businessentityid DESC
) cte
```

Comment: I tried that also but it's not the result I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Most important thing is why do you want to use `CROSS APPLY` or `INNER JOIN` ?

you can try in this manner,

```
Select A.firstname, cte.jobtitle 
from Person.Person A
cross apply 
(
Select * from
(
Select top 3 * 
from HumanResources.Employee B
order by businessentityid DESC
)B
where B.BusinessEntityID= A.BusinessEntityID
) cte
```

Now you can easily understand why you were getting different result .